# How would I implement strafe using opengl in java?

Tags: opengl, camera

This is my gluLookAt setup:

```
 glu.gluLookAt(x,y,z,    // eye location
               x + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle)),
               y,
               z - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle)), // point to look at (near middle)
               0.f,1.f,0.f); // the "up" direction
```

The x, y, z are the coordinates and change when turning left and right and moving forward and backward. But I'm having difficulty implementing strafe right and left. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When strafing, you need to shift both you `eyePoint` and `targetPoint` by the same amount.

Comment: Sorry what is the target point? These are the only variables i'm using: private double x=-40, y=5, z=50;
    private double eyeAngle = 0;
    private double distance = 5;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured everything out. If you have move forward and turn left and right, then strafe is actually simple. Strafe right, for example, is basically you turning 90 degrees to the right, moving forward, and then turning 90 degrees back to the left.

My forward was:

```
x += distance*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle)); 
z += -distance*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle));
```

You don't want to change the eyeAngle, because you still want to look in the same direction. For strafe right, you want to move as if you turned 90 degrees to the right and then went forward, similarly for left. So right would be my forward method above with an angle 90 to the right of my original eyeAngle,  but because you want to keep eyeAngle the same, you don't change the variable, you just add 90 to it.

So, the right strafe method would be:

```
    x += distance*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle+90)); 
    z += -distance*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle+90));
```

Left would be subtracting 90. It is actually pretty simple after you've got forward and the overall glulookat set up. Thanks for the help everyone, it did aid me in understanding how it all works.

Comment: great...you finally did it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea about the GLU APIs but given X,Y and Z co-ordinates,

```
a Left relative to it's current Y rotation is,
    position of X -= distance*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Y-90));
    position of Z += distance*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Y-90));


a Right relative to it's current Y rotation is,
    position of X -= distance*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Y+90));
    position of Z += distance*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Y+90));
```

Try replacing Y with eyeAngle coz thts what is the rotating point.

Comment: I tried x -= stepSize*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(y-90))             z += stepSize*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(y-90)); and it didn't work

Comment: it did not. just as an examples this is my forward: x +=  distance*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle));
                z += -distance*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle));

Comment: Okay just replace Y with eyeAngle. e.g. for stafeLeft x -=stepSize*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(eyeAngle-90))